# Remove spaces recursively in Python

Tags: python, recursion

I'm trying to remove spaces recursively in python. I started off with the base case of an empty string to return self.phrase, assuming it would return None. Am I wrong in this? Here's the code:

```
class palindrome:

    phrase = ""

    def remove_spaces (self, phrase):
        if self.phrase == "":
            return self.phrase
        if self.phrase[0] != " ":
            return self.phrase[0] + remove_spaces (self.phrase[1:])
```

However, the unittest is failing:

```
class test_remove_spaces(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_remove_spaces_none(self):
        self.assertEquals (remove_spaces (None), None)
```

The problem from the test fail is due to an error. Not exactly sure why remove_spaces is not accessible. Is it a nesting problem since I was trying to keep the data hidden?:

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\******\Dropbox\CS2\CS2_Assignment2\Assignment2.py", line 24, in test_remove_spaces_none
    self.assertEquals(remove_spaces(None), None)
NameError: global name 'remove_spaces' is not defined
```

Comment: I hate to be that person, but why are you doing this recursively? Iterating through the characters isn't particularly pythonic, either. Unless you're set in doing this recursively, I would suggest just using phrase.replace(" ", "")

Comment: @user3697163 I'm putting my money on homework requirement. Which is OK. But that is probably why.

Answer (score 1):

`remove_spaces` is a method in your `palindrome` class. You need to instantiate your class first before you can call `remove_spaces`.

```
class test_remove_spaces(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_remove_spaces_none(self):
        obj = palindrome()
        self.assertEquals (obj.remove_spaces(None), None)
```

Also, I would suggest reading through the [PEP8 style-guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Classes typically follow camel case, first letter being uppercase, so your class can be renamed to:

```
class Palindrome:
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use a regular expression?

```
import re
subject = "   test "
no_space = re.sub(r"\s+", "", subject, 0, re.IGNORECASE)
```

Comment: Regex seems a bit heavyweight for this problem. I would suggest using the str.replace method as I mentioned on the original post